# Indexing windows server for searching

Tags: windows-server-2003, search, indexing

Is there a way to index file shares on a windows file server so that they can be quickly searched by end users, that isn't part of sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Windows Search (or the built in Vista/Win7 search to index shares.  The downside is that each client maintains their own index.  This seem like a less than optimum solution.  Alternative might be to use a web-based indexer like SharePoint, Google, etc. to do it.  Microsoft has a high-end indexing solution too.  There are open source indexers as well like Apache's [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Search Service, built in to windows server. (Formerly called: Index Server)

Details to set up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567543/147637